# Rxjava2, zipped iterable and interval, executes only a single mapped observable

Tags: rx-java2

I have this the following scenario I need to achieve:

- **perform each network call for a list of request object with 1 second delay each**

and I have this following implementation using rxjava2

- emit an **interval** stream
- emit an **iterable** stream
- **zip** them to emit each item from the iterable source

which by far has no problem and I fully understand how it works, now I integrated the above  to the following

- **map** each item emitted from **zip** into a new observable that defer/postpone an observable source for a network call
- each **mapped-emitted** observable will perform an **individual** network call for **each** request

which I ended up with the following code

```
 Observable
            .zip(Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), Observable.fromIterable(iterableRequests), new BiFunction<Long, RequestInput, RequestResult>() {

                @Override
                public RequestResult apply(@NonNull Long aLong, @NonNull final RequestInput request) throws Exception {
                    return request;
                }
            })
            .map(new Function<RequestResult, ObservableSource<?>>() {

                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> apply(@NonNull RequestResult requestResult) throws Exception {

                    // map each requestResult into this observable and perform a new stream
                    return Observable
                            .defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<?>>() {
                                // return a postponed observable for each subscriber
                            })
                            .retryWhen(new Function<Observable<Throwable>, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                                // return throwable observable
                            })
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Observer<ObservableSource<?>>() {

                //.. onSubscribe {}
                //.. onError {}
                //.. onComplete {}

                @Override
                public void onNext(ObservableSource<?> observableSource) {
                    // actual subscription for each of the Observable.defer inside
                    // so it will start to emit and perform the necessary operation

                }
            });
```

but the problem is, it executes the Observable.defer source, only  **ONCE**, but keeps on iterating(by putting a Log inside the map operator to see the iteration).

Can anyone guide me please on how can I achieve what I want, I exhausted alot of papers, drawing alot of marble diagrams, just to see where Im at on my code,
[image]

I dont know if the diagram I created illustrate the thing that I want, if it does, I dont know why does the sample code dont perform as the diagram portraits

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is fine, but the map thingy is a bit unneeded, what you are doing is mapping each `RequestResult` to an `Observable`, and then manually subscribe to it at the `Observer.onNext()`, actually the `defer` is not necessary as you're creating separate `Observable` for each `RequestResult` with different data, `defer` will occur at each subscribe yoy do at `onNext()`, and the map occur as you observed for each emission of the zipped `RequestResult`. 
what you probably need is simple `flatMap()` to map each `RequestResult` value to a separate `Observable` that will do the network request, and it will merge back the result for each request to the stream, so you'll just need to handle the final values emission for each request instead to subscribe manually to each `Observable`.
Just keep in mind that order might be lost, in case some requests might take longer than your delay between them.

```
Observable.zip(Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), Observable.fromIterable(iterableRequests),
        new BiFunction<Long, RequestInput, RequestResult>() {
            @Override
            public RequestResult apply(@NonNull Long aLong,
                                       @NonNull final RequestInput request) throws Exception {
                return request;
            }
        })
        .flatMap(new Function<RequestResult, ObservableSource<?>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<?> apply(RequestResult requestResult) throws Exception {
                return createObservableFromRequest(requestResult)
                        .retryWhen(new Function<Observable<Throwable>, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                            // return throwable observable
                        })
            }
        })
        .subscribe(new Observer<ObservableSource<?>>() {
            //.. onSubscribe {}
            //.. onError {}
            //.. onComplete {}
            @Override
            public void onNext(ObservableSource<?> observableSource) {
                //do something with each network result request emission
            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you for the response, but the defer is really necessary in my case as it performs alot of retryWhen operations on that particular stream, and I really need to create seperate (new) observable to update any parameters inside that stream of event(this was actually a bigger part of my previous issues),I think I stripped of the code too much, sorry for that,  but I actually found out why it didnt work as the stream didint tell me there was a NullPointerException inside the operation

Comment: OK, now it's clear why you need the `defer()`, but in any case you can use it either with `flatMap`, just create it inside it instead of map, I think it is more convenient and correct way.

Comment: yeah actually, and thank you for the advise, seems like flatmap is more appropriate and more efficient in my case as I just want to transform those emitted items by the zip operation. thank you again @yosriz, but would you mind to guide me about error handling of observable streams? I found out why my code didnt work, as somewhere inside the operations, there was an NPE that has never been thrown back to me :(

Comment: sorry again, I just found out that I left my subscribers' onErrors() empty, as in doing nothing, then I put a stacktrace call ".printstacktrace" , and made the retrofitclient null, then there is, an NPE caught by the stream but never made the running process explode., so this is how rxjava handles errors .... we are responsible on handling the bad possibilities along the stream..

Comment: great to hear you find the problem, although it wasn't the problem I was pointing to...

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work, as somewhere inside the Observable.defer, my retrofitclient was null,

```
retrofitClient.getApiURL().post(request); // client was null
```

my retrofitClient was null ( i looked somewhere in the code and I noticed i was not initialized, and I initialized it properly and made it work)

now can anybody tell me why Rx didnt throw an exception back to the original observable stream? theres no NullPointerException that occurred, Im confused